# How do you properly return variables

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I am trying to learn Java and am playing around with variables as well as jaunt for a basic program I have in mind. My goal is to use the use the main method to print out the data I collect in my other methods. I am sure the answer is blindingly obvious and I have read the Java docs, but am still confused as to why this is not working. When I run the program it seems to run without printing the data I want. Furthermore, if I add a sysout statement to the spfivehundred method than it shows the spfivehundred method looping infinitly and printing the data I want to come out of the main method.

```
import com.jaunt.*;
import com.jaunt.component.*;

public class mainthread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        spfivehundred();
        double spfivehundreded = spfivehundred();
        System.out.println(spfivehundreded);
    }

    public static double spfivehundred() {
        UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();

        try {
            userAgent.visit("http://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500");
            String spfivehundredget = userAgent.doc.findFirst(
                    "<span class=\"arial_26 inlineblock pid-166-last\">")
                    .getText();
            double spfivehundred = Double.parseDouble(spfivehundredget.replace(
                    ",", ""));

        } catch (JauntException e) {

            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return spfivehundred();

    }

}
```

Comment: It will help if you don't reuse names (`spfivehundred`) even if technically legal. Your return statement is calling the function again.

Comment: `return spfivehundred();` performs a recursive call, i.e. calls itself indefinitely. It should be `return spfivehundred;` You'll need to declare `spfivehundred` prior to the `try` `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are recursing in your `spfivehundred` method - you want to return the value you parsed. And a value if your method fails, or throw an exception. Something like,

```
public static double spfivehundred() {
    UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();

    try {
        userAgent.visit("http://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500");
        String spfivehundredget = userAgent.doc.findFirst(
                "<span class=\"arial_26 inlineblock pid-166-last\">")
                .getText();
        return Double.parseDouble(spfivehundredget.replace(
                ",", ""));
    } catch (JauntException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return Double.NaN; // <-- no result.
}
```

Then you currently drop one result **and** I wouldn't name everything `spfivehundred`; something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // spfivehundred();
    double result = spfivehundred();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: A better "exception" return value would be `Double.NaN`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! One question, what does the "return -1;" statement mean. Why the -1?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah. That is better.

Comment: @IsaacTherrien A value to indicate there was no result, the other option would be throwing an exception *or* changing the result type to `Double` and returning `null`... *or* make it an `Optional<Double>`.

Comment: @IsaacTherrien That was an *example* of a special return value in case of error. In reality, it's up to *you* to decide that the method should do if the `JauntException` happens. In simple programs like what you've displayed, **don't** catch the exception, but let it ride, i.e. add `throws JauntException` to the `spfivehundred()` method declaration, and to the `main()` method. The JVM will then end the program and print the error for you, if it happens.